# powershell check sharepoint URLs

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a script that iterates through a bunch of sharepoint URLs and verifies that they exist.

From what I can find, it looks like this should work:

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential ("username", "password", "domain")
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString("http://sharepointurl")
```

This is not working for me ... I keep getting:

Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you use fiddler or wireshark to inspect the request to ensure that it has an auth section on it?

Answer (score 12):

If your current credentials have perms on the Sharepoint site then skip the net credential and just use the default credentials e.g.:

```
$webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`(Invoke-webrequest -URI "https://www.yoururl.com").Content`

Ref: [Display all content with Invoke-WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702328/display-all-content-with-invoke-webrequest)