# Display all content with Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, curl

So I decided to start using PowerShell rather than Command Prompt. And I want to run `curl`. Very different output then discover that `curl` is an alias to `Invoke-WebRequest` in PowerShell.

Using PowerShell `curl` in the same way as real `curl`, I only get part of the content displayed.

I have seen that I can put the output of PowerShell `curl` into a variable and then use `$variable.Content` to display all of the content but that seems extra work over real `curl`.

Is there an option to show all of the content directly? I can't see one in the help.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Unlike the [`curl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) command line utility `Invoke-WebRequest` returns an object with various properties of which the content of the requested document is just one. You can get the content in a single statement by expanding the property like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'http://www.example.org/' | Select-Object -Expand Content
```

or by getting the property value via dot-notation like this:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest 'http://www.example.org/').Content
```

---

Alternatively you could use the Windows port of [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html):

```
& curl.exe 'http://www.example.org/'
```

Call the program with its extension to distinguish it from the alias `curl` for `Invoke-WebRequest`.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest 'http://www.example.org/' | Select-Object -Expand RawContent` if you want to see the response headers

Answer (score 7):

Well, if you are bothered with extra typing this is the shortest way to achieve that (well, at least I can think of):

```
(iwr google.tt).content
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
$res=Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.google.fr/" 


#to view html of body
$res.ParsedHtml.body.innerHTML

#to view text of body
$res.ParsedHtml.body.innerText
```